# Php code to update the profit column in database in every 1 hour

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, update

I'm currently working web based hyip software but the problem I'm facing there is that I need a php code that will be increasing the user profit in every 1 hour but I still don't get it.
In that application, I have a table called ph_list whereby all deposit made by the user will be stored.
In that table, I have a column called the tracking_id(which is unique), Amount, Percentage...

But after making deposit, I want the amount donated by the user should be increasing in every 1 hour , which will be in percentage column....

Please I need someone to shield more light on this please!!

Comment: Are you sure you need to update the database every hour? Isn't it enough to know, when requested, how many hours have elapsed since a certain moment? [... and you don't need to update *anything*]

Comment: Yes I need to update the database every hour for the 1% interest to reflect on users dashboard!

Comment: I don't think you do. You actually *only need to have the data updated immediately before the users look at the dashboard*. So, it is actually the dashboard that should trigger the update. At that point, count the number of hours, and update accordingly.

Comment: Yes please can you help me with that please?

Comment: How do I do that please I need your help

Answer (score 1):

Never update it.  No `UPDATE, no`TRIGGER`.  Simply compute it based on the current time minus the time at which the user's entry was established.

There are standard formulas for "compound interest"; MySQL has all the math formulas needed to do the arithmetic.